# How to change values in one dataframe using interpolated values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, interpolation

I have a **dataframe J** and I am currently using a code where I am performing some simple operations on this dataframe. The current code is at the end.

**What I want to get**

There is another dataframe named CFD_L2. This data frame has 3 columns: **xpos, ypos, and velocity**. Now in the **J dataframe**, I want to update the **fishspeed** using the **velocity** (from the CFD_L2 dataframe based on the **xpos** and **ypos**) by adding it to the current fish speed (which is calculated using the distance formula).

So the algorithm steps would go something like this.

1. The code will work as it is right now.
2. Then the code will go through the **J dataframe** row by row and check the **X.wcentroid..cm.** and **Y.wcentroid..cm.** position and then look for the corresponding **xpos** and **ypos** in the CFD_L2 dataframe (it will have to do interpolation in the CFD_L2 to find those exact **xpos and ypos** as of **X.wcentroid..cm.** and **Y.wcentroid..cm.**) and pick the **velocity** from there and add it to the already calculated **fishspeed** in the **J dataframe**.

If someone could help me in building this piece of missing code, I will be very grateful.
Thank you in advance. :)

```
#The J dataframe with fish data
    J <- read.csv("D:/MSCA-RIBES/Experiments_2021/R/Fish3.csv") 

#The dataframe from where I want to extract velocity values and add them to the J dataframe
CFD_L2 <- read.csv(paste0("D:/MSCA-RIBES/Ansys Fluent/L2 Model/2/plane_L2.csv"))   

J$fishspeed[1] <- 0                     #assigning 0 as the starting fish speed
J$distance <- NA                        #create the distance column

for (j in 2:nrow(J)) {
  #calculating distance from distance formula (both in x and y)
  J$distance[j] <- abs(J$X.wcentroid..cm.[j]-J$X.wcentroid..cm.[j-1])
  #calculating fish speed in x and y
  J$fishspeed[j] <- J$distance[j]/(0.02)
  #assigning positive and negative signs to the velocity 
  J$fishspeed[j] <- ifelse(J$X.wcentroid..cm.[j]-J$X.wcentroid..cm.[j-1] < 0,J$fishspeed[j],-J$fishspeed[j])
}
```

**The MRE for the J dataframe is:**

```
    structure(list(frame = 0:9, ACCELERATION.pcentroid..cm.s2. = c(0, 
629.05127, 484.44827, 134.24866, 168.38608, 392.61456, 534.75482, 
41.96627, 69.14757, 263.45416), ACCELERATION.wcentroid..cm.s2. = c(0, 
153.44151, 105.59528, 202.80286, 118.33042, 131.19977, 297.22171, 
77.18677, 61.05884, 230.39838), ANGLE = c(3.11237, 3.08248, 3.07114, 
-0.10611, -3.11957, 3.14106, -3.10649, -0.083, -0.10303, -0.03427
), ANGULAR_A.centroid = c(0, -202.77382, 3.05533, -7495.91406, 
15768.4209, -8005.69336, -236.58276, 7894.97559, -23338.25391, 
15657.55469), ANGULAR_V.centroid = c(0, -4.05548, -3.99437, -153.91264, 
161.45576, 1.3419, -3.38975, 154.50975, -312.25534, 0.89574), 
    AX = c(0, -2041.00696, -2051.98926, 2269.85352, -2141.18726, 
    -2167.49097, -1622.0061, 2030.82153, 2261.80957, 2080.86084
    ), AY = c(0, 35.52997, 171.27061, -312.76627, -215.38239, 
    -268.79153, -71.59282, -323.54047, -368.00244, -342.0845), 
    BORDER_DISTANCE.pcentroid..cm. = c(0.55631, 0.53378, 0.49995, 
    0.43229, 0.40511, 0.42238, 0.3941, 0.3742, 0.33689, 0.29436
    ), MIDLINE_OFFSET = c(0.08791, 0.06723, -0.00448, -0.01109, 
    0.03456, 0.08484, 0.04347, -0.05106, -0.02282, -0.04411), 
    SPEED.wcentroid..cm.s. = c(0, 3.06883, 4.4169, 3.33479, 1.50971, 
    2.36096, 3.75872, 2.57346, 2.4795, 3.60654), SPEED.smooth.wcentroid..cm.s. = c(0, 
    3.06883, 4.4169, 3.33479, 1.50971, 2.36096, 3.75872, 2.57346, 
    2.4795, 3.60654), SPEED.pcentroid..cm.s. = c(0, 12.58103, 
    12.6677, 1.91822, 1.10765, 6.40553, 8.74503, 4.52055, 1.54492, 
    4.30662), SPEED..cm.s. = c(0, 40.82632, 38.38213, 48.67908, 
    43.71307, 44.80465, 34.20591, 44.49779, 47.65644, 42.92842
    ), VX..cm.s. = c(0, -40.82014, -38.12928, 48.57462, -43.69948, 
    -44.57827, -34.06067, 44.18293, 47.29947, 42.68103), VY..cm.s. = c(0, 
    0.7106, 4.39839, -3.1874, -1.0899, -4.49826, -3.14883, -5.28418, 
    -5.82202, -4.602), X.wcentroid..cm. = c(24.36773, 24.42594, 
    24.48949, 24.47197, 24.4474, 24.41499, 24.48632, 24.52759, 
    24.54886, 24.48055), X..cm. = c(23.48358, 23.55132, 23.66335, 
    25.46098, 23.59798, 23.55584, 23.73378, 25.36998, 25.47358, 
    25.40248), speed = c(0, -3.387, -5.6015, -89.8815, 93.15, 
    2.107, -8.897, -81.81, -5.18, 3.555), Y.wcentroid..cm. = c(29.98473, 
    30.00418, 30.06554, 30.1299, 30.14745, 30.11311, 30.13684, 
    30.1676, 30.2124, 30.23556), Y..cm. = c(29.97619, 29.99894, 
    30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), frame.1 = 0:9, midline_length = c(78.90591, 
    79.62206, 78.76032, 72.85874, 74.39832, 78.09255, 74.34315, 
    69.12302, 73.73874, 75.47749), midline_x = c(23.15566, 23.22088, 
    23.33655, 25.76223, 23.28882, 23.23115, 23.42478, 25.65648, 
    25.7786, 25.71614), midline_y = c(29.98568, 30.01886, 30.11412, 
    29.96982, 30.09885, 30.05787, 30.03924, 30.00842, 30.02002, 
    30.11098), missing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), normalized_midline = c(0.1907, 0.08918, -0.12857, Inf, 
    Inf, 0.1425, Inf, Inf, Inf, 0.00509), num_pixels = c(1376L, 
    1304L, 1261L, 1165L, 1214L, 1240L, 1198L, 1020L, 917L, 884L
    ), segment_length = c(0.10935, 0.11035, 0.10918, 0.10098, 
    0.1031, 0.10823, 0.10307, 0.0958, 0.1022, 0.1046), time = c(0, 
    0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18), timestamp = c(0L, 
    20000L, 40000L, 60000L, 80000L, 100000L, 120000L, 140000L, 
    160000L, 180000L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

**The MRE for CFD_L2 is:**

```
    structure(list(ï..xpos = c(17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 
19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 
23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 
28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30), ypos = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30), velocity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 3600:3621, class = "data.frame")
> CFD <- dput(CFD_L2[3000:3621,])
structure(list(ï..xpos = c(24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 
26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 
1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 
6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 
11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 
15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 
19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 
23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 
28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 
3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 
7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 
12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 
16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 
20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 
25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 
29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 
4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 
9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 
13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 
17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 
22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 
26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 
0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 
5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 
10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 
14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 
18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 
22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 
26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 
1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 
6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 
11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 
15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 
19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 
23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 
28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 
3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 
7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 
12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 
16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 
20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 
25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 
29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 
4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 
9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 
13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 
17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 
22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 
26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 
0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 
5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 
10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 
14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 
18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 
22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 
26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 
1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 
6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 
11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 
15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 
19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 
23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 
28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 
3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 
7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 
12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 
16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 
20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 
25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 
29.3911, 30, 0, 0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 
4.208, 4.8076, 5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 
9.0048, 9.6044, 10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 
13.8015, 14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 
17.9987, 18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 
22.1959, 22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 
26.3931, 26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30, 0, 
0.6104, 1.21, 1.8096, 2.4092, 3.0088, 3.6084, 4.208, 4.8076, 
5.4072, 6.0068, 6.6064, 7.206, 7.8056, 8.4052, 9.0048, 9.6044, 
10.204, 10.8036, 11.4032, 12.0028, 12.6024, 13.2019, 13.8015, 
14.4011, 15.0007, 15.6003, 16.1999, 16.7995, 17.3991, 17.9987, 
18.5983, 19.1979, 19.7975, 20.3971, 20.9967, 21.5963, 22.1959, 
22.7955, 23.3951, 23.9947, 24.5943, 25.1939, 25.7935, 26.3931, 
26.9927, 27.5923, 28.1919, 28.7915, 29.3911, 30), ypos = c(28.4519, 
28.4519, 28.4519, 28.4519, 28.4519, 28.4519, 28.4519, 28.4519, 
28.4519, 28.4519, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 
29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.0367, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 
29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.6306, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 29.7032, 
29.7032, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 
29.764, 29.764, 29.764, 29.7641, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 
29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8149, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 29.8575, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 29.8931, 
29.8931, 29.8931, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 
29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9228, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 
29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9476, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 29.9683, 
29.9683, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 
29.9856, 29.9856, 29.9856, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30), velocity = c(0.330644, 
0.329754, 0.328881, 0.32803, 0.327197, 0.326397, 0.325606, 0.324901, 
0.324086, 0.333277, 0.355185, 0.361662, 0.365557, 0.36612, 0.366069, 
0.365769, 0.36523, 0.364538, 0.36373, 0.362818, 0.361821, 0.360753, 
0.35963, 0.358459, 0.357247, 0.356, 0.354722, 0.353418, 0.352091, 
0.350742, 0.349373, 0.347988, 0.34659, 0.345182, 0.343769, 0.342353, 
0.340936, 0.33952, 0.338106, 0.336697, 0.335294, 0.3339, 0.332517, 
0.331146, 0.329788, 0.328444, 0.327117, 0.325806, 0.324513, 0.323239, 
0.321985, 0.320752, 0.319542, 0.318356, 0.317199, 0.316068, 0.314981, 
0.313911, 0.312959, 0.311883, 0.322129, 0.355185, 0.363593, 0.368111, 
0.367753, 0.367014, 0.366066, 0.364919, 0.363646, 0.36226, 0.360762, 
0.359165, 0.357484, 0.35573, 0.353914, 0.352043, 0.350122, 0.348158, 
0.346154, 0.344117, 0.34205, 0.339955, 0.337837, 0.335707, 0.333571, 
0.331434, 0.329296, 0.327155, 0.325015, 0.32288, 0.320751, 0.318635, 
0.316536, 0.314459, 0.312406, 0.310379, 0.308381, 0.306414, 0.304479, 
0.302579, 0.300714, 0.298886, 0.297097, 0.295349, 0.293644, 0.291986, 
0.290374, 0.28883, 0.287319, 0.28598, 0.284482, 0.297058, 0.355185, 
0.363776, 0.368044, 0.367231, 0.366003, 0.364605, 0.362995, 0.361223, 
0.359317, 0.357291, 0.355163, 0.35295, 0.350665, 0.34832, 0.345926, 
0.343492, 0.341029, 0.338544, 0.336047, 0.333531, 0.330992, 0.32844, 
0.325888, 0.323344, 0.320813, 0.318297, 0.315795, 0.313317, 0.310862, 
0.308435, 0.306042, 0.303687, 0.301371, 0.299096, 0.296864, 0.294674, 
0.292529, 0.290428, 0.288373, 0.286364, 0.284403, 0.282491, 0.28063, 
0.27882, 0.277068, 0.275369, 0.273749, 0.272168, 0.270772, 0.26923, 
0.273745, 0.355185, 0.363629, 0.367413, 0.365998, 0.364098, 0.362012, 
0.359662, 0.357117, 0.354424, 0.351611, 0.348708, 0.345741, 0.34273, 
0.33969, 0.336636, 0.333585, 0.330548, 0.327536, 0.324558, 0.321613, 
0.318697, 0.315811, 0.312956, 0.310134, 0.307352, 0.30461, 0.301911, 
0.299262, 0.296662, 0.294113, 0.291616, 0.289172, 0.28678, 0.28444, 
0.282152, 0.279915, 0.277729, 0.275594, 0.27351, 0.271478, 0.269499, 
0.267573, 0.265703, 0.263888, 0.262135, 0.260439, 0.258827, 0.257257, 
0.255879, 0.254365, 0.257847, 0.355185, 0.362998, 0.365966, 0.363626, 
0.360696, 0.357498, 0.353976, 0.350253, 0.346405, 0.342487, 0.338546, 
0.334619, 0.330732, 0.326901, 0.323142, 0.319466, 0.315882, 0.312397, 
0.309015, 0.305731, 0.302538, 0.299427, 0.296387, 0.293415, 0.290512, 
0.287676, 0.284912, 0.28222, 0.279597, 0.277043, 0.274554, 0.272128, 
0.269761, 0.267452, 0.2652, 0.263004, 0.260862, 0.258774, 0.25674, 
0.25476, 0.252835, 0.250965, 0.249152, 0.247395, 0.245701, 0.244066, 
0.242517, 0.24101, 0.239702, 0.238267, 0.241565, 0.355185, 0.361546, 
0.363057, 0.359114, 0.354442, 0.349417, 0.344091, 0.33868, 0.333301, 
0.328027, 0.322914, 0.317991, 0.313262, 0.30873, 0.304388, 0.300235, 
0.296262, 0.292463, 0.288831, 0.285358, 0.282031, 0.278838, 0.275759, 
0.272781, 0.269892, 0.267084, 0.264359, 0.261717, 0.259156, 0.256676, 
0.254271, 0.251936, 0.249667, 0.247459, 0.245309, 0.243213, 0.241171, 
0.239185, 0.237251, 0.235371, 0.233545, 0.231772, 0.230054, 0.228393, 
0.226794, 0.225254, 0.2238, 0.222388, 0.221181, 0.219853, 0.223142, 
0.355185, 0.358426, 0.357147, 0.350153, 0.342432, 0.334571, 0.326802, 
0.319386, 0.312407, 0.305876, 0.299775, 0.294077, 0.288752, 0.283769, 
0.279097, 0.27471, 0.270587, 0.266702, 0.26303, 0.259559, 0.256273, 
0.253155, 0.250185, 0.247341, 0.244601, 0.24195, 0.239378, 0.236884, 
0.234466, 0.232124, 0.229851, 0.227647, 0.225509, 0.223431, 0.221411, 
0.219449, 0.217544, 0.215694, 0.213897, 0.21215, 0.210456, 0.208813, 
0.207225, 0.205691, 0.204217, 0.2028, 0.201471, 0.200178, 0.199102, 
0.197898, 0.201424, 0.355185, 0.351162, 0.344025, 0.331348, 0.318952, 
0.307578, 0.297319, 0.288221, 0.280144, 0.27292, 0.266391, 0.260433, 
0.254969, 0.249936, 0.245284, 0.240977, 0.236985, 0.233269, 0.22979, 
0.226527, 0.223459, 0.22057, 0.217835, 0.215235, 0.212749, 0.210354, 
0.208034, 0.205778, 0.203583, 0.201449, 0.199372, 0.197355, 0.195397, 
0.193494, 0.191649, 0.189862, 0.188129, 0.18645, 0.18482, 0.183236, 
0.181703, 0.180218, 0.178785, 0.177401, 0.176074, 0.174801, 0.173616, 
0.172457, 0.171535, 0.170464, 0.174493, 0.355185, 0.332171, 0.312964, 
0.291611, 0.27427, 0.260516, 0.249259, 0.239881, 0.231899, 0.224974, 
0.218858, 0.213366, 0.208383, 0.203828, 0.199648, 0.195798, 0.192242, 
0.188944, 0.185872, 0.183002, 0.180315, 0.177793, 0.175412, 0.173158, 
0.171012, 0.168948, 0.166953, 0.165012, 0.163117, 0.161275, 0.159479, 
0.157734, 0.156041, 0.154393, 0.152796, 0.151249, 0.149745, 0.148289, 
0.146876, 0.145504, 0.14418, 0.142895, 0.14166, 0.140468, 0.139328, 
0.138236, 0.13723, 0.136238, 0.135498, 0.134582, 0.139459, 0.355185, 
0.282913, 0.24435, 0.215714, 0.197642, 0.185308, 0.175938, 0.16843, 
0.162168, 0.156806, 0.152122, 0.147953, 0.14419, 0.140766, 0.137634, 
0.134754, 0.132089, 0.129614, 0.127312, 0.125167, 0.123165, 0.121292, 
0.119524, 0.117856, 0.116273, 0.114751, 0.113282, 0.111856, 0.110461, 
0.109108, 0.107786, 0.106505, 0.105263, 0.104052, 0.102877, 0.101737, 
0.100625, 0.099551, 0.098509, 0.097498, 0.096526, 0.095582, 0.094679, 
0.093808, 0.092977, 0.092184, 0.091463, 0.09074, 0.090249, 0.089581, 
0.094982, 0.355185, 0.179687, 0.128743, 0.10633, 0.095915, 0.089352, 
0.084455, 0.080592, 0.077389, 0.074657, 0.07228, 0.070174, 0.068279, 
0.066559, 0.06499, 0.06355, 0.062219, 0.060983, 0.059834, 0.058765, 
0.05777, 0.056844, 0.055967, 0.055143, 0.054365, 0.053615, 0.052894, 
0.052197, 0.051511, 0.050851, 0.050202, 0.049576, 0.04897, 0.048376, 
0.047801, 0.047243, 0.046694, 0.04617, 0.045659, 0.045162, 0.044689, 
0.044226, 0.043788, 0.043365, 0.042961, 0.042579, 0.042237, 0.041884, 
0.041676, 0.041351, 0.046253, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = 3000:3621, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Would you edit your post and add `dput(your_data)` ?

Comment: @MohamedDesouky I did it. Also changed the question to make it more simple.

Comment: @MohamedDesouky bro could you please reply to my question, at your convenience? Thank you

Comment: What output you expect ?

Comment: When I run the above code, in my J dataframe, I have already a fishspeed column which I am calculating from the distance formula (in the above code). I want to update that fishspeed column in J dataframe by adding the velocity from the CFD_L2 dataframe. 

The criteria to chose the right velocity from CFD_L2 dataframe is to compare the X and Y positions of fish in J dataframe with those of CFD_L2 dataframe for each row and choose the respective velocity from CFD_L2 dataframe to be added to fishspeed in J dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `for loop` , you can use

```
J$distance <- c(0 , abs(diff(J$X.wcentroid..cm.)))

J$fishspeed <- J$distance <- c(0 , diff(J$X.wcentroid..cm.)) / 0.02
```

then you can try this to add velocity

```
for(i in 1:nrow(J)){
  y_min <- CFD_L2$ypos[which.min(abs(J$Y.wcentroid..cm.[i] - CFD_L2$ypos))]
  x_min <- which.min(abs(J$X.wcentroid..cm.[i] - subset(CFD_L2 , ypos == y_min)$ï..xpos))
  J$velocity[i] <- subset(CFD_L2 , ypos == y_min)$velocity[x_min]
}
```

Comment: The above code will replace your `for loop` , what do you want about the other data.frame `CFD_L2`?

Comment: Thanks for this optimization. Now you see there is fishspeed in J dataframe being calculated. I want to update this fishspeed (for each row) by adding velocity from the CFD_L2 dataframe. BUT the criterion to choose the velocity from CFD_L2 is to match the X.wcentroid..cm. and Y.wcentroid..cm. from J dataframe to xpos and ypos in CFD_L2 dataframe and choose the velocity of that row. SO I have to match the values from 2 columns in J dataframe to two columns in CFD_L2 dataframe. If values are not exactly the same, I want to use the minimum closest values.

Comment: Do you mean by adding velocity from the CFD_L2 , add column named `velocity`?

Comment: not really. For each row in the J dataframe, I have to pick a velocity value from the CFD_L2$velocity based on the criterion I wrote above. So it will be a row-wise operation. 
Not just simply adding the CFD_L2$velocity to J$fishspeed.

Comment: Try this with your data .

Comment: The code runs but I am not sure if the resulting numbers are true. Could you tell briefly what the code is doing step by step? Thank you

Comment: If you see `CFD_L2` carefully , you will see that `y` values repeated with different values of `x` , so the code first find the closest value of `y` which is `y_min` then using the indices of these `y`'s i search for the closest value of `x` and finally get the corresponding velocity , hope this clear for you .